# WPF Dynamic Cursor

Tags: c#, wpf, sharpdx, direct2d

I am creating a vector graphic editor in WPF. I am rendering the artwork using a D3DImage that has been customised using SharpDX so that I use it with Direct2D. When an item is selected, resize handles appear around the selected item. I want the cursor to change when the user hovers over these resize handles, but they are rendered in Direct2D and are not WPF elements. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you’re doing your own rendering to D3DImage, you gotta do your own hit testing.

If your geometry’s relatively simple (boxes, circles, polylines, not too many of them), you can hit test these handles shapes in mouse move event handler. Either manually, or by using e.g. [FillContainsPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742749(v=vs.85).aspx) D2D APIs.

Or, if you aren’t doing something very color-sensitive like a desktop publishing, you can encode resize handles in the color of your shapes. Use a couple of least significant bits of the blue channel (human eyes are least sensitive to blue), read the color under the mouse, change cursor accordingly to the blue color value.

Or, you can switch to DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_UNORM for your render target (looks like D2D supports that format), this way you can add much more per-pixel data to your image without any visible artifacts (use lower bytes of each of the 3 color channels). This however complicates rendering, you’ll need to do one more pass to convert the texture into A8R8G8B8 for the WPF.

P.S. I wonder why don’t you use WPF elements instead? 2D vector graphics there is rather advanced. You can easily create/manipulate/fill/outline these [shapes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path(v=vs.110).aspx) programmatically (just place then on a [canvas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas(v=vs.110).aspx)), this way WPF will handle all these hit tests, and rendering, and more.

Comment: I'm using Direct2D because I want my program to be as high-performance as possible. However, I solved this simply by hit testing for the handles in the MouseMove handler and then setting the cursor.

Comment: @333 What makes you think D2D rendering is significantly more performant than WPF? They both use D3D under the hood. WPF uses older version of D3D, some things are indeed more efficient in D2D because of that. However D2D implements immediate mode rendering, it’s gonna waste time managing these GPU resources (GPUs don’t support immediate drawing anymore).